# OpenCV - python 3.x and windows - what version of Numpy?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, opencv, numpy

I downloaded openCV from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv and installed it. When I tried to run it:

```
import cv2
```

I got error message:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
 5.0.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I guess I need to set up virtual enviroment and install different version of Numpy, but what exact version of Numpy I need to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the anaconda distribution for that.
I'm using it and it works great with opencv on windows.

You can download it from here:
https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Then use conda to install opencv

`conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

conda comes with pre installed numpy, scipy, pandas etc and makes deployment on windows painless (since it ships with the build-chain).

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try your solution. In my case simply upgrading to Numpy 1.10 (turns out this is version a) worked.

Comment: Do you know if we can use numpy versions 1.11+ with `menpo opencv` or `conda-forge opencv` ?   I'm trying to use both

Answer (score 1):

You need numpy version 11 or above . You can find it in the below link.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy